# service-worker.js and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to implement Google Analytics in my PWA application, I built the pages with Polymer and now I have to implement GA into it. I created one GA code and a new dimension for offline and in service-worker.js I pasted the code right at the beginning:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize({
  parameterOverrides: {
    cd1: 'offline',
  },
});
```

Now I am a bit lost as T don't know how to access this data and what I suppose to do in order to make it work. From where it reads the UA-XXXX? if only this code is appended in service-worker.js? Do I have to implement ga.js in index.html too? Any idea of this implementation process is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Can't you add the GA code to the index.html of app?

Comment: No i dont know all the necesary steps to make it work for PWA applications.

Comment: Are you trying to track offline events?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes thats right